# using libtool gdb from within geany

Tags: gdb, autotools, libtool

I'm working on a project that uses GNU autotools, so in order to debug the code using gdb, I'm running gdb from within libtool:

```
libtool --mode=execute gdbtui foobar
```

Is it possible to somehow do this from within the geany IDE? Or to somehow run libtool e geany instead of gdb?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the actual debugging plugins [Debugger](http://github.com/geany/geany-plugins/blob/master/debugger/README) and the more recent and maintained [Scope](http://github.com/geany/geany-plugins/blob/master/scope/README) plugins, you can run arbitrary build commands in Geany itself. The latter is described [in the manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#build-menu) as well as by a helpful article [on the wiki](https://wiki.geany.org/howtos/configurebuildmenu).

The basic idea is that you need to use the Build menu's "Set Build Commands" dialog to configure custom commands as described in the manual (with nice screenshots and descriptions of all the fields and placeholders). You can access the manual for your current version from the Help menu inside Geany.

Comment: If you could give a short summary on how to do it in your answer, that would be great — otherwise, your answer is dependent on its links, which is frowned upon here (they go dead, it’s annoying, etcetera). Thanks.